# PHP don't repeat code ( don't repeat yourself )

Tags: php, codeigniter

i am using codeigniter (template) library in codeigniter. I always repeat template library code in every function. will you help me to reduce the code.

```
public function index(){
    //Load View in template file
        $this->template->title('Contacts')
        ->set_layout($this->admin_home_layout)
        ->set_partial('header', 'admin/admin_share/admin_header')
        ->set_partial('sidebar', 'admin/admin_share/admin_sidebar')
        ->set_partial('footer', 'admin/admin_share/admin_footer')
        ->set_partial('hidenbar', 'admin/admin_share/admin_hidenbar')        
        ->build('admin/admin_home');
    }
```

These 4 lines i am using in every function. how i can use one time in one controller and how to get in function.

```
->set_partial('header', 'admin/admin_share/admin_header')
    ->set_partial('sidebar', 'admin/admin_share/admin_sidebar')
    ->set_partial('footer', 'admin/admin_share/admin_footer')
    ->set_partial('hidenbar', 'admin/admin_share/admin_hidenbar')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I do it ( applicable for any framework in PHP that has similar way of rendering views):

Suppose that the controllers look like this:

```
<?php 
class AdminController extends BaseController{
    public function viewData($id){
        // do something
        $this->render('something static 1');
        $this->render('customview');
        $this->render('something static 2');
        $this->render('something static 3');
    }

}
?>
```

What I would do is create a base controller to do this rendering tasks ( and more repetitive stuffs):

```
<?php 

class MyBaseController extends BaseController{

    protected function renderAll($param){
        if(empty($param)){
            return false;
        }
        $this->render('something static 1');
        $this->render($param);
        $this->render('something static 2');
        $this->render('something static 3');
        return true;
    }
}

?>
```

Once this is done, I will simply inherit the newly created controller in all my controllers, such as:

```
<?php 
class AdminController extends MyBaseController{
    public function viewData($id){
        // do something
        $this->renderAll('customview');
    }

}
?>
```

You can re-use this in any controller action you want to, just inherit the custom base controller class.

Comment: In Ci3 the first letter of class name should only be upper case same applies for filenames.

Comment: @wolfgang1983 I wanted to generalize the answer. CI does not even have the Controller suffix does it?Anyway,  I am more sort of a Yii2 guy than CI :P

Answer (score 0):

you can set them in the constructor:

```
public function __construct() {

    parent::__construct();

    //Do your stuf here

}
```

Or you could create a function for it:

```
function set_partials() {
    $this->template->set_partial('header', 'admin/admin_share/admin_header')
    ->set_partial('sidebar', 'admin/admin_share/admin_sidebar')
    ->set_partial('footer', 'admin/admin_share/admin_footer')
    ->set_partial('hidenbar', 'admin/admin_share/admin_hidenbar')
}
```

In this second case, you're index would look like this:

```
public function index(){
    //Load View in template file
    $this->template->title('Contacts')
    ->set_layout($this->admin_home_layout);

    $this->set_partials();

    $this->template->build('admin/admin_home');
}
```

Comment: but some time i want to changer my $this->template->build('admin/admin_home');  view page how do this?

Answer (score 0):

i suggest a different logic, just a custom array for your partials like this :

```
protected $partials = [
    'header' => 'admin/admin_share/admin_header',
    'sidebar' => 'admin/admin_share/admin_sidebar',
    'footer' => 'admin/admin_share/admin_footer',
    'hidenbar' => 'admin/admin_share/admin_hidenbar'
];
```

and use this function to build layout

```
public function build_layout()
{
    $this->template->title('Contacts')->set_layout($this->admin_home_layout);
        foreach($this->partials as $k => $partial){
            $this->template->set_partial($k,$partial);
    }
    $this->template->build('admin/admin_home');

}
```